# Incorrect passport number/name in New Zealand visa

Tags: visas, new-zealand

I provided an incorrect passport number in my online New Zealand visitor visa application (one digit was duplicated). The visa application was approved and was linked against this incorrect number. How can I get my passport number corrected?

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your two accounts merged, so that you can edit your original question.

Answer (score 38):

New Zealand visas are generally issued electronically and are linked to your passport number.  Therefore it is important that the passport details on your visa are correct.

Immigration New Zealand's [web site](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/about-us/our-online-systems/applying-for-a-visa-online/immigration-online/evisas) contains the following information on fixing visa errors:

> **eVisa does not match your passport**
>
> If there is an error in the visa details listed in your eVisa, contact Immigration New Zealand (INZ) immediately. For example if your name or your passport number is wrong.
>
> If your personal details in the eVisa do not match your passport, you may be delayed when travelling to New Zealand.
>
> eVisa will only capture your first and last name. Middle names are not always included. As long as the names that do appear are correct, the missing names do not affect the integrity of the visa or the ability to travel to (or remain in) New Zealand.
>
> [Contact us](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/contact)

Comment: Note: Just below the quoted part there is a "Contact us" link that leads to https://www.immigration.govt.nz/contact - including it in the answer may help people save a bit of stress, and I bet they are stressed a lot if they  need this.